# Banach and Hausdorff spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am reading a book on function spaces and I really struggle understanding  the following statement:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach Spaces and $V$ a Hausdorff topological vector space such that (continuously embedded)
>   $$
> X\hookrightarrow V \hookleftarrow Y.
> $$
>   Then, $X\cap Y$ and $X+Y$ are linear subspaces of $V$ and these spaces are Banach spaces with:
>   $$
> \|z\|_{X+Y}=\inf_{z=x+y}\|x\|_X+\|y\|_Y\qquad\|z\|_{X\cap Y}=\max\{\|z\|_X,\|z\|_Y\}
> $$

Why do we want $V$ to be a topological Hausdorff space? Where can it go wrong without the Hausdorff property?

Comment: There is no chance for a space that is not Hausdorff to be a Banach space...

Comment: ah, I see now! Thank you.

Comment: @ziggurism: But the Banach space topologies here are not the topology of $V$, so I don't think that's relevant.  On the other hand, if you allowed the indiscrete topology on $V$ the "continuously embedded" requirement would be vacuous.